# C# P/Invoke array of arrays

Tags: c#, c, arrays, pinvoke

I searched this question but google gave nothing.
Is there any way to marshal array of arrays?

```
//C
typedef struct SomeStruct
{
    float matrix[7][12];
} SomeStruct;

//C#
public struct SomeStruct
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = ???)]
    public float[][] matrix;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a linear array in the C# code:

```
public struct SomeStruct
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 7*12)]
    public float[] matrix;
}
```

You'll need to convert from a 2D index to a linear index for convenience.

```
int LinearIndex(int i, int j)
{
    return i*12 + j;
}
```